# What to do with announcement about ttf-mscorefonts-installer?

Tags: apt, fonts

After last update of Ubuntu 18.04 LTS to newest kernel 4.15.0-55-generic 23.7.2019 I started to receive daily automatic notifications after each booting that I should install ttf-mscorefonts-installer.

But when I made command 'sudo apt-get install ttf-mscorefonts-installer'
in the Terminal, I get reply that it is already installed in newest version (3.6ubuntu2).

In which program or service this ttf-mscorefonts-installer is needed ?
What can I do to stop / prevent  these automatic announcements ?

Comment: what is the actual notification you get? I would purge it and install it again if I was you. Could it be you neglected to accept the EULA the 1st time? :)

Comment: Rinzwind hi, thank you for your advised. I did as you advised i.e. 1.) at first purge and 2.) after that install. The result was positive, no more notification after reboot. Thank you very much !

Comment: cool; I assumed as much. i will make it an answer. There is likely a method to redo confirming the EULA as that is likely to be the issue

Answer (score 2):

Purge it and install it again.

```
sudo apt purge ttf-mscorefonts-installer
sudo apt install ttf-mscorefonts-installer
```

That will make it ask for the EULA again.
Could it be you neglected to accept the EULA the 1st time? Because that is possible and would stop fetching the actual fonts (the package does not contain the fonts but makes a webrequest to fetch them).

Comment: My PC started to receive same notifications again. I've made 2 times as you advised, but new installation not happened because ''.... E: File  https://vorboss.dl.sourceforge.net/project/corefonts/the fonts/final/arial32.exe was not received.  Could not wait for server fd - select (11: Recource is temporarily not in use) [IP: 5.10.152.194 443] . E: Download failed. ...'' Maybe they have a break in service ?

Comment: That has nothing to do with you. That is a dead website.

Comment: I tried this: at first: sudo apt-get purge remove ubuntu-restricted-extras and after that sudo apt install ubuntu-restricted-extras and then full re-start (i.e. power entirely off/power on): result: so far no notifications after this start.

Comment: Evidently my trying yesterday is/was not the right solution, because today 28.7. when I started this same desktop (PC), I received the same notification again.